# Error installing opencv library for nodejs

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm

Please, could someone help me? I need to install the opencv library for nodejs, after solving a series of errors I came across one that I can not solve.

ERROR:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto-barePlayer\sistema-test\node_modules\opencv
npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

npm ERR! C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto-barePlayer\sistema-test\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

npm ERR! C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto-barePlayer\sistema-test\node_modules\opencv\build\test_nativemat.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

If anyone please can help me, I will be eternally grateful.

I have installed microsoft tools 2015, cleared mpn cache among other things.
I thank you, forgive me the trouble

Comment: `The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.` Where does the path "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" comes from?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, being very sincere I do not know just rode the npm i opencv , I went to check and realized that I do not have these files, I think I incorrectly installed Microsoft visual Studio